# Implementing Predictive Posterior Distribution Using Stan

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior, stan

**Background**

I had an example that sought to demonstrate the *posterior predictive distribution* in the context of a normal measurement model. The data that was used is as follows:

```
speed <- c(28, 26, 33, 24, 34, -44, 27, 16, 40, -2, 29, 22, 24, 21, 25, 30, 23, 29, 31, 19, 24, 20, 36, 32, 36, 28, 25, 21, 28, 29, 37, 25, 28, 26, 30, 32, 36, 26, 30, 22, 36, 23, 27, 27, 28, 27, 31, 27, 26, 33, 26, 32, 32, 24, 39, 28, 24, 25, 32, 25, 29, 27, 28, 29, 16, 23)
```

The Stan model provided is as follows:

````
```{stan output.var="NMM_PPD"}
data{
  int<lower=1> n;
  vector[n] y;
}

parameters{
  real y_mu;
  real y_lsd;
}

transformed parameters{
  real<lower=0> y_sd;

  y_sd = exp(y_lsd);
}

model{
  y ~ normal(y_mu, y_sd);
}

generated quantities{
  vector[n] y_rep;

  for(i in 1:n){
    y_rep[i] = normal_rng(y_mu, y_sd);
  }
}
```
````

We then call the following sampling command:

````
```{r}
data.in <- list(y=speed, n=length(speed))
model.fit <- sampling(NMM_PPD, data=data.in)
```
````

This example demonstrated that the normal measurement model does not seem to be suitable for these data. Why? Because while the mean and median of the original data `y` are almost in centre of these statistics calculated on replicated data sets sampled from the posterior predictive distributions, this was not the case for the minimum, the maximum or the inter-quartile range. Also, the histogram of the original data set looks significantly different compared to histograms on replicated data sets from the posterior predictive distribution.
This is illustrated below.

We first use the `extract()` function to extract our replicated data sets from the `model.fit` object:

````
```{r}
yrep <- extract(model.fit, pars = "y_rep")[[1]]
```
````

Histograms:

````
```{r}
ppc_hist(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 11), ])
```
````

[image]

Mean:

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep)
```
````

[image]

Maximum:

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "max")
```
````

[image]

And others are calculated as follows:

```
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "median")

ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "min")

stat <- function(x) diff(quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)))
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = stat)
```

**Problem**

I now want to fit the following model:

$Y_i | \mu, \sigma \sim t_{\nu}(\mu, \sigma)$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ independent

$\mu \sim N(0, 1000^2)$

$\sigma \sim \text{Half_Cauchy}(0, 5)$

Where $t$ represents a $t$ random variable, and the symbol $\nu$ represents the degrees of freedom.

I want to experiment with different values of $\nu$ to see which value is appropriate for modelling the aforementioned statistics (max, mean, median, min, quantile).

My current Stan code is as follows:

````
```{stan output.var="NMM_PPD"}
data{
  int<lower=1> n;
  vector[n] y;
}

parameters{
  real y_mu;
  real y_sd;
  real nu;
}

model{
  y ~ student_t(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  y_mu ~ normal(0, 1000);
  y_sd ~ cauchy(0, 5);
}

generated quantities{
  vector[n] y_rep;

  for(i in 1:n){
    y_rep[i] = student_t_rng(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  }
}
```
````

And I draw samples from the model using the following code:

````
```{r}
data.in <- list(y=speed, n=length(speed))
model.fit <- sampling(NMM_PPD, data=data.in)
```
````

The results are obtained as follows:

````
```{r}
print(model.fit, pars = c("y_mu", "y_sd", "nu"), digits = 5)
```
````

[image]

So we have $\nu = 2.56$.

However, I'm unsure if I've gone about this correctly. Is this the value of `nu` that best fits the model?

I've spent a long time researching other Stan implementations of predictive posterior distributions, but I'm still not 100% sure that I've done this correctly.

https://magesblog.com/post/2015-05-19-posterior-predictive-output-with-stan/

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4e97/66371e7572609594a4f68fc74b7c6fe70767.pdf

https://magesblog.com/post/2015-05-19-posterior-predictive-output-with-stan/

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work.

Comment: Is part of the problem that you are modeling a strictly positive quantity using a normal distribution? If you log transformed that might work better or consider other distributions (e.g. Weibull is often used for wind speeds).

Comment: @Björn Thanks for the response. That could very well be the case, but for this specific case I am only interested in using a t-distribution.

Comment: You might want to include nu as a parameter as well (instead of data) and see how Stan fits it. Then I'd look at incorporating some sort of informative priors (your sd of 1000 seems way too large given the data generated by the process).
The reason your histograms look so weird is because the t-distribution with low nu tends to get quite extreme outliers; this doesn't seem to be the case in your speed dataset. As such nu = 1 might not be a great fit to your data. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MauritsM This really helped, and I have edited the main post accordingly. Thank you for the assistance. So would the value of nu produced by Stan the one that leads to the best fit?

Comment: @ThePointer you're welcome :-) Right now your value of nu is the one that best fits the data + model combination. You should probably still do some posterior predictive checks and other model checking tricks to see if it matches your expectations. If not, you should probably add more prior information on nu to tilt it toward your expectations. Good luck!

Comment: Also, in your Stan code, you should constraint nu and y_sd with <lower=0>

Comment: @MauritsM Will do. Thank you again for the clarification. Your short response was actually thoroughly illuminating. :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Comment: @MauritsM I thought I'd just follow-up with something important. When I constrain `nu` and `y_sd` with `<lower=0>`, I get totally different values. For instance, for `nu`, I get extremely large values like 2.467434e+14. So it seems that I need to keep the constraint `<lower=0>` off.

Comment: It seems that setting the lower bound `lower=0` on `y_sd` is not the problem — it changes nothing. The problem seems to be setting the lower bound on `nu`.

Comment: Interesting! I don't know enough about Stan to know exactly why that happens. I was under the impression that you should always constrain your parameters if that is required by the distribution. They then get transformed to an unconstrained scale and the appropriate Jacobian matrix is automatically calculated.

Comment: This may be relevant along with $$C_{pk}$$ used to all process engineers to predict their yields and improve them by the ratio of sd to upper and lower acceptance limits and indicate process FOM for values >1